# Missing values in predictor variable when running random forest classification in R

Tags: r, random-forest, qgis

I have run into a new error message while trying to run the rf classification. The error message reads: "Error in na.fail.default(list(class = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : missing values in object".

Below is a sample of my train for your reference.
Let me know if anyone has any insights that could help me troubleshoot this. Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s7oo.png)

I have tried to address the issue by adding the parameters na.action=na.roughfix and na.action=na.omit, but each time I run the classification, I receive a new error message that reads: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '2022_r_1' not found", even though '2022_r_1' is a column in my train data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.